# iPhone restarts after API call

Tags: ios, iphone

I am facing a very weird issue: my iPhone is restarting.
This issue occurs in a particular scenario only.

Step 1: I have a sync process in which I'm loading data for the whole app. So I'm basically doing a heavy API call by uploading 4-5 camera captured images and syncing the app data;

Step 2: After syncing, I'm pressing the iPhone home button to make the app go in background;

Step 3: I'm locking the iPhone screen(by using side button);

After a few seconds I'm seeing the apple logo and the phone seems to restart. This is not replicating when the app is connected in debug mode. I checked the debug navigator app is using only 125 MB of memory, disk and network values is 0%. Energy Impact is showing high, I'm not sure this is due to high energy impact. I'm facing this issue only on iOS 12.4.

[image: app's memory leak]
[image: camera Sample memory leak]

Comment: which iphone you used for testing? Did you tried commenting image upload/processing codes?

Comment: I'm testing it on i-phone 6, I just tested that if I didn't upload the images and just do the normal app sync i-phone doesn't restart

Comment: but I wasn't able to understand why uploading images effectinf iphone os, As all the process of uploading and syncing is a serial process(synchronous api calling)

Comment: is this only happening when you go to background mode while downloading?\

Comment: I went to background after compleating api's calls

Comment: it should be a memory issue. And it probably be related to the images. Use instruments for profiling

Comment: Is this reproduceable on multiple devices?  I would suspect a hardware issue, probably the battery given the age of the device. Does the problem occur if you have the phone connected to a charger?

Comment: Can you try on a simulator and see if the same thing happens?

Comment: @Lal Krishna I checked the instruments, the cpu usage is normal and there is not any memory leaks

Comment: @Paulw11 yes this issue was reported by my client and I'm also able to replicate it, this seams to battery problem or something, when phone is charging this issue is not replicable, I was not able to understand in the debugger as soon as app goes in background all the cpu ect. usage is zero, and all the process is synchronous and all process is completed then why this kind of thing is happening

Comment: @LearningPhase when the device is connected in debug mode and if i use gallery images this issue is not replicable

Comment: If you are facing this issue only on 12.4 it is probably apple's bug. You can't restart the phone if even you would try, no way. Only your app may be crush but never restart the phone. Maybe you are having issue with your iPhone. You can try with some other device to make sure if your phone is ok.

Comment: i was able to debug the issue it is a memory leak and like arises when I'm using camera, I created a sample project with camera opening code and it is showing memory leak there. the difference there is that it is not restarting the phone in sample.

Comment: I have uploaded some screenshots please check

Comment: Note that if you've truly found an OS bug that crashes the operating system, this is very rare and valuable. I suggest reporting it to Apple - the jailbreak community may also find it useful if the grey hat scene appeals to you.

Comment: yeah I just filed a bug report, hopefully get will get a reply soon

Comment: @ParvBhasker In case you're unaware, Apple's bug reporting system is infamously unresponsive and opaque. Chances are this will be fixed in the next version with no indication in your report, or will be closed as a duplicate. Have you tested it in an iOS 13 beta?

Comment: yes previously I reported a bug on apple, but I'm not getting same issue on 12.4.1 I guess the issue is only with the iOS 12.4 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the *phone* (or possibly just springboard) restarts, and not just your application means this is Apple's bug. You're not supposed to be able to crash iOS even if you try.

Finding a likely cause will be hard since the system is not behaving the way it's supposed to. The device's logs may have more information from things other than your app. This may be a system API breaking due to any number of actions from your application.

Often with this kind of thing the next OS version will fix it, but if that's not the case or it's important to track down I would try removing ways you're interaction with the system (background APIs, notifications, etc.) and see if anything fixes the issue.

If you find the problem, you may even be doing things the "correct" way according to the documentation and have to find a workaround. If you have the time you can [submit a bug to Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) so the underlying issue has a better chance of being fixed.

Comment: i was able to debug the issue it is a memory leak and like arises when I'm using camera, I created a sample project with camera opening code and it is showing memory leak there. the difference there is that it is not restarting the phone in sample.

Comment: I have uploaded some screenshots please check

Comment: That leak looks like pretty small...that shouldn't even cause your application to crash, much less the whole OS

Answer (score 0):

It seems when your app is in the background and phone locked, Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) closes some connection or deallocates a resource that makes the iPhone restart. Are you closing all connections and removing all references once the upload is complete?

Comment: the issue is with the uipicker camera code, it is showing memory leak

Comment: I have uploaded some screenshots please check

Comment: Not really sure what's happening here

Answer (score 0):

Phones do not spontaneously restart just because of an app’s actions. You’re having an issue with your phone, not with a program. You need to repair or replace the phone.

Comment: i was able to debug the issue it is a memory leak and like arises when I'm using camera, I created a sample project with camera opening code and it is showing memory leak there. the difference there is that it is not restarting the phone in sample.

Comment: I have uploaded some screenshots please check