# memory leak while capturing image from camera

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller

there was a strange issue happening in my app, the issue is while I try to capture images from camera like 4-5 images captured using camera. there is a memory leak showing in instruments.

Due to this memory leaks if I put my app in background and lock the screen the iphone restarts.

please check the screen shot of the leak information[image: leak information]

I'm using a simple picker to capture image from camera and then dismissing it. then why is there this leak.

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

 picker.delegate = self
 picker.allowsEditing = false

 picker.sourceType = .camera
 self.present(picker, animated: true)



public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        processSelectedImage(image: image)
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: more info about the crash]

Comment: show us a memory graph of this leak

Comment: I have updated some more info please check, after taking image from camera and saving it to temp memory the phone takes around 123mb of memory for a moment as shown in the image

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522269/iphone-restarts-after-api-call ? The problem is your phone.

Comment: actually I was able to debug the issue, I guess problem is with the uipicker camera code, I created a sample and in that sample it is showing memory leak, there I'm just opening the camera and closing it and still shows memory leak

Answer (score 0):

This is due to low memory of your device and a lot of other processes are running in app, try to cleanup the device and try again.

Better way is to restart your device and run again.

Comment: When you are saving image in temp memory you need to reduce image size and save them in temp memory like:

`let mydata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)`

This can help you to save memory.

Comment: yes previously I was converting it to 0.8, but even I commented all the code in the picker delegate method and I'm just capturing image and dismissing view, still it is showing memory leak, I created a new sample project and it is showing memory leak  in the camera code

Comment: I've tried your code and it is working fine in iPhone XR. The memory issue is due to your device, can you tell me which device you are using for testing?